# Longstitch error make: command: Command not found *** No rule to make target

Tags: sequence-analysis, assembly, wgs, long-reads, scaffold

I installed [Longstitch](https://github.com/bcgsc/LongStitch) and ran the test script with no issues. The output files matched the expected output files. But when I am now trying to run Longstitch on my own data I am getting this error.

```
(medaka) operations@LabPC1:~/medaka/longstitch-1.0.5$ ./longstitch run draft=~/medaka/~medaka/medaka_results/consensus.fa reads=~/medaka/combined.fastq G=4.5e8
make: command: Command not found
make: command: Command not found
make: *** No rule to make target'/home/operations/medaka/~medaka/medaka_results/consensus.fa.fa', needed by'/home/operations/medaka/~medaka/medaka_results/consensus.fa.cut250.tigmint.fa'.  Stop.
```

I changed the file name from .fasta to .fa for my draft assembly because it requires a .fa file, but now I am getting ".fa.fa" What is wrong here?

Comment: Please provide a link and/or additional information about what Longstitch is. It would also be useful if you could provide a few lines of input and output (e.g. from both the example data and your own data).

Answer (score 1):

Could you download it from `conda` and try again? Its here, https://docs.conda.io/en/main/miniconda.html

Then,

```
conda create --name myenv
conda activate myenv
conda install -c bioconda longstitch
longstitch ...
```

Conda avoids all the build stuff.

---

Notes

If you find that "conda" is slow and doesn't ever load.

There is an alternative to conda called **mamba**, this is fast and designed to address this exact issue. I have never needed to use it so the following is a rough guide only.

Download and install via

```
conda create --name myenv
conda activate myenv
conda install -c conda-forge mamba
```

The documentation is here, https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/mamba.html

I've never used it but the idea is ...

```
mamba create -n mambaenv <list of packages>
mamba activate mambaenv
```

The list of packages could be left blank for now, then,

```
mamba install "Python>=3.10.0" numpy pandas pathlib
mamba install longstitch
```

Can also do

```
mamba install -n mambaenv longstitch
```

**NOTE** longstitch exists strictly in -c bioconda. You do not seem to search and install via channels in mamba

You search for a package and its dependencies via

```
mamba repoquery search longstitch
mamba repoquery depends -a longstitch
```

It is important to place a virtual environment between the system Python and package Python (don't want a system corruption).

---

Finally ...
For `fa.fa` ... hmmmm, try `ls *.fa` and check for `.fa.fa` files.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue I can see is the filenames, and should be easily solvable.

Simply put, LongStitch is *very* particular about filenames. It expects the input draft to have the extension .fa, and the input reads to have any from a range of extensions (your .fastq is perfectly fine, though).

The main issue is that LongStitch expects the extensions to be *missing* from the command. So if your draft is draft is called `consensus.fa` and your reads are  `combined.fastq`, then the command would include something like `draft=consensus reads=combined`, not `draft=consensus.fa reads=combined.fastq`.

(unsure if it accepts input from different directories, or whether you'll need to move your input to the same directory as well)

More generally, when having issues with a particular tool which is available via github, I would encourage you to have a look at the 'Issues' or 'Help' section. What I normally do is to delete the 'is:issue is:open' terms in the search bar, which allows me to search for my bug among older, potentially solved issues (e.g. https://github.com/bcgsc/LongStitch/issues/54), and also generally to check that the software is still supported.

Good luck!

(*that said, M_'s suggestion of using mamba is generally a good one, and has helped me with another LongStitch bug)